# maximum height is no more than 111

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I am trying to implement Qcompleter in a QlineEdit. When I try to change the maximum size of QAbstractItemView nothing happens, it remains at a default maximum size.

Image depicting the maximum size of QCompleter.

[image]

If I put a maximum Height below this size, it works and limits. But if I put a value above it does not work and remains at the default size.

test code of what I'm trying to do:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)


        p = QtGui.QPalette()
        p.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtCore.Qt.white)

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(p)
        frame = FrameAutoComplete()
        complete = QtWidgets.QCompleter(['dsadasdsadsa', 'PSDPASDA', 'PDWQEWQEWQE', 'POSTAL ASDSa', 'PODSADsadsa', 'gfgsdfgsdfgsd', 'PSDPASDA', 'PDWQEWQEWQE', 'POSTAL ASDSa', 'PODSADsadsa'])
        complete.setPopup(frame)
        complete.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        entry = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        entry.setCompleter(complete)


        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.show()


class FrameAutoComplete(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.NoDropShadowWindowHint)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        #self.setMaximumHeight(400) #NOT WORK
        #self.setMaximumHeight(50) #WORK

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you want to set a higher height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the popup is calculated taking into account the [`maxVisibleItems`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) points out:

> #### maxVisibleItems : int
>
> This property holds the maximum allowed
>   size on screen of the completer, measured in items
>
> By default, this property has a value of 7.

And is also limited by the maximum height allowed by the popup itself, in conclusion it is equivalent to:

```
height_popup = min(maximumHeightof the popup, 
                   height calculate using maxVisibleItems items of QCompleter)
```

which is equivalently implemented in [the source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/util/qcompleter.cpp#L944).

So assuming you want to increase the height of the popup to show more items then the solution is to increase the [`maxVisibleItems`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) property:

```py
complete.setMaxVisibleItems(number_of_visibles_items)
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer solved my problem, but another one came up. When I set a spacing, the popup behaves differently. No longer appears all items I set in setMaxVisibleItems, returning to the previous question, limiting the popup height and not showing all items of setMaxVisibleItems. Any solution ?